# Node JS handling multiple post requests for same route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am building a Node JS app with Express JS and MongoDb. In my index.hjs (using hogan) page there is a login and forgot password functionality. Now both the forms have action as action="/" and method="POST"

I am handling my login post request in my index.js like this

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var login = require('login.js');



router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    //calls a login.js function and passes it the params
    login.login(email, password, req, res);
});
```

Now my problem is that the forgot password submit is suppose to do a POST too but I am not sure how it should be handled. Do I do it in the same post? I figured that maybe using next() is the key but how?

How can we handle multiple posts requests in general?

PS: Fairly new to Node JS so pardon my logic and code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting you to create new route to handle the forgot password request because you  will not have "var password = req.body.password;" in case of forgot password so better to create new route for it:-

```
router.post('/forgot', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    //calls a login.js function and passes it the params
    login.login(email, password, req, res);
});
```

We use next() in the case of [Middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) in node.

Answer (score 1):

Use two different path for your login and recovery posts.

For exemple: /login and /recoverpw

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    //calls a login.js function and passes it the params
    login.login(email, password, req, res);
});

router.post('/recoverpw', function(req, res, next) {
    //your recovery code
});
```

Comment: hi i'm also strucked in same problem. here as you said i used one more route but getting 404 not found of the page.